# error assigning values to struct within a struct golang

Tags: go, struct

I came across this situation where I was trying to assign values to a struct within a struct.  There is no compiler error, but it does panic when you run it.  Does Go have a different way to handle this data structure?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Label struct {
    ID     int
    Labels []struct {
        ID   int
        Name string
    }
}

func main() {
    l := Label{}
    l.ID = 100

    l.Labels[0].ID = 200
    l.Labels[0].Name = "me"

    fmt.Println(l.ID)
    fmt.Println(l.Labels[0].ID)
    fmt.Println(l.Labels[0].Name)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IiuXpaDvF1W

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for a slice is `nil` so it has no elements, and you cannot assign to index 0 because it doesn't exist yet.

You can use append to add a new element to that slice using:

```
l.Labels = append(l.Labels, struct{
    ID   int
    Name string
}{
    ID:   200,
    Name: "me",
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uAWdQdh0Ov7

In addition, your use of an inline/anonymous struct here means you'll need to redeclare the type when you `append`. Consider adding another declared type:

```
type SubLabel struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

type Label struct {
    ID     int
    Labels []SubLabel
}

// ...

l.Labels = append(l.Labels, SubLabel{
    ID:   200,
    Name: "me",
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4idibGH6Wzd

Comment: That makes sense.  I agree with adding the SubLabel declared type.  I can see how this could go multiple layers down and that would make it a lot easier to read and better code re-usability.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark my answer as the answer to your question. :)